# How to call user defined functions in C++?

Tags: c++

Below you will find my dismal attempt to create a user defined function. I am trying to do an assignment that calculates the area and cost of installing carpet for various shapes. I am also suppose to keep a running total of them. In addition the assignment requires that I use a used defined function. Right now all it does is accept the input of 1 and ask "What is the length of the side: ". It then loops back to the selection menu. It does not calculate a total much less keep track of the total. What am I doing wrong in creating the user defined function and how can I incorporate it to keep a running total till they exit?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void square(double);

const double UNIT_PRICE = 2.59;
const double LABOR_COST = 32.5;
const double PIE = 3.14;
const double TAX = .0825;

int main() {

  int selection;
  int sqrSide = 0;

  // declare and initialize the variables for the shape
  int sqrTot = 0;

  do {
    // get input from user as to what they want to do
    cout << "Carpet Area Shape" << endl;
    cout << "1. Square" << endl;
    cout << "2. Rectangle" << endl;
    cout << "3. Circle" << endl;
    cout << "4. Triangle" << endl;
    cout << "5. Done" << endl;
    cout << "Type a number to continue: ";
    cin >> selection;
    cout << endl;

    // loop through the solutions based on the user's selection
    switch (selection) {
    case 1:
      cout << "What is the length of the side: ";
      cin >> sqrSide;

      square(sqrSide);

      if (sqrTot > 0) {
        cout << "Shape: Square" << endl;
        cout << "Side: " << sqrSide << endl;
        cout << "Area: " << sqrTot << endl;
      }

      cout << endl;

      system("pause");

      break;

    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5: // exit

      system("cls");

      break;

    default:
      "You have made an invalid selection. Please choose a number from the "
      "list.";
      cout << endl;
    }

    // loop through if the user is still making a valid selection
  } while (selection != 5);

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}

void square(double) {
  double sqrSide = 0;
  double sqrTot = 0;
  double sqrArea;

  sqrArea = sqrSide * 4;

  // get the total area and store it as a variable
  sqrTot += sqrArea;

  if (sqrTot > 0) {
    cout << "Shape: Square" << endl;
    cout << "Side: " << sqrSide << endl;
    cout << "Area: " << sqrTot << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the actual problem. An error message? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: Right now all it does is accept the input of 1 and ask "What is the length of the side: ". It then loops back to the selection menu. It does not calculate a total much less keep track of the total.

Comment: `void square(double)` you don't even use the input parameter?? `sqrTot ` is local to the `square()` function and will be recalculated for each call.

Comment: @BWMustang13 try mi solution

Comment: If your function is intended to calculate something, why does it returns `void`?

Comment: @eyllanesc I have a feeling you are still missing something. The OP has serious misconceptions about the scope of variables, parameters and return values.

Comment: The answer @eyllansec provided compiles but it does not accumulate a total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by πάνταῥεῖ in a comment, it seems that you've a few misconceptions regarding scope of variables, about parameters and about return values. Let's see if we can't dispel some of those.

First of all, lets talk about scope. When we declare a variable inside a block delimited with `{` and `}`, the variable only exists inside that block. Code that follows the block *cannot access the variable*.

So, this is okay:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 2;

int c = a*b;
```

But, this is not, since the values of a and b are no longer available:

```
{
 int a = 3;
 int b = 2;
}
 int c = a*b;
```

Next, lets talk about parameters. These are the inputs to functions which the function will use in order to complete its task. While their name is irrelevant and essentially meaningless, it will certainly help you and others of you give them meaningful names. Some programming languages and indeed, students of some disciplines don't follow this maxim and can produce code that's harder to follow than it need be. The implementation of Basic found in 20 year old Texas Instruments calculators and physicists, I'm looking at *you*!

Consider the following functions, (whose bodies I've ommitted for brevity):

```
double calcArea(double a)
{
 ...
}

double calcArea(double b)
{
 ...
}
```

They both suck. What's `a` stand for, how about `b`?
A far better pair might resemble:

```
double calcArea(double radius)
{
 ...
}

double calcArea(double sideLenOfSquare)
{
 ...
}
```

Lastly, lets talk about return values. In each of the 4 preceding functions, the declaration begins with `double`. This means that we can expect to get back a value of type double from the function. However, this is just coding - there's no magic and as such, we need to actually let the compiler know what this value will be. Extending the two previous functions, we might come up with some something like the following:

```
double calcArea(double radius)
{
  return 3.1415926535 * (radius * radius);
}

double calcArea(double sideLenOfSquare)
{
  return sideLenOfSquare * sideLenOfSquare;
}
```

Now as it turns out - even these two simple functions are not all they've cracked-up to be. Namely, the first function uses a constant - π (Pi or 3.141....) This already exists (and with *far* better precision than I've used) in the `math.h` header file. If this file is included, we then have access to the `#define`d constant, `M_PI`.
Next, both of these functions have the same name and take the same number of parameters of identical type. The compiler can't possibly know which one you'd like to invoke. At a minimum, they should have different names. Perhaps something like `calcCircleArea` and `calcSquareArea`. Now, the compiler knows which function you're referring to and will happily compile this part of the code. Errors may exist elsewhere, but these are a different matter.

A little research on `function overloading` will provide resources that can explain the problem and solution to functions with the same name far better than I am both able and inclined to try. :)

Comment: Thank you! That was an incredibly helpful response!

Answer (score 2):

When you declare the prototype of the function you can omit the parameter but in the implementation you must place it.

change:

```
void square(double)
{
    double sqrSide = 0;
    double sqrTot = 0;
    double sqrArea;

    sqrArea = sqrSide * 4;

    //get the total area and store it as a variable
    sqrTot += sqrArea;

    if (sqrTot > 0) {
        cout << "Shape: Square" << endl;
        cout << "Side: " << sqrSide << endl;
        cout << "Area: " << sqrTot << endl;
    }


}
```

to:

```
void square(double sqrSide)
{
    double sqrTot = 0;
    double sqrArea;

    sqrArea = sqrSide * 4;

    //get the total area and store it as a variable
    sqrTot += sqrArea;

    if (sqrTot > 0) {
        cout << "Shape: Square" << endl;
        cout << "Side: " << sqrSide << endl;
        cout << "Area: " << sqrTot << endl;
    }


}
```

and also change:

```
case 1:
                cout << "What is the length of the side: ";
                cin >> sqrSide;

                square(sqrSide);

                if (sqrTot > 0) {
                    cout << "Shape: Square" << endl;
                    cout << "Side: " << sqrSide << endl;
                    cout << "Area: " << sqrTot << endl;
                }

                cout << endl;

                system("pause");

                break;
```

to:

```
case 1:
                cout << "What is the length of the side: ";
                cin >> sqrSide;

                square(sqrSide);

                system("pause");

                break;
```

Comment: You should explain the changes instead of just dumping code.

Comment: Also that doesn't solve the primary problem as it appears from the OP.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what's OP?

Comment: @eyllanesc - **O**riginal **P**oster